# How do I fix the blink of an light theme?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dark/light switch. I keep users dark/light preference with cookies. So when they visit again, they will see their preferred theme. But there is an annoying problem. Each time I refresh the page, the page reveals the light theme for a short time and then takes on the dark theme again. How to fix this?

```js
const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');

function switchTheme(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
  localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark'); //add this
    }
    else {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
  localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light'); //add this
    }    
}

toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);

const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme') ? localStorage.getItem('theme') : null;

if (currentTheme) {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', currentTheme);

    if (currentTheme === 'dark') {
        toggleSwitch.checked = true;
    }
}
```

```css
:root {
    --bg-color: #fff;
    --panel-bg: #fff;
    --panel-bg-hover: #dcd8d8;
    --panel-border: #22a7f0;
    --panel-title-color: #22a7f0;
    --panel-title-hover: #0072b1;
    --panel-subtitle-color: #ffa500;
    --panel-text-color: #000000;
    --panel-button-bg: #dc4a4a;
    --panel-button-hover-bg: #d83535;
    --panel-button-text-color: #ffd7f8;
    --panel-button-text-hover-color: #ffd7f8;
    --input-bg: #e6e6e6;
    --input-border-color: #ff0000;
    --input-label-color: #ff0000;
    --input-label-color-focus: #ff0000;
    --input-text-color: #000000;
    --search-input-bg: #fff;
    --table-shorting: #22a7f0;
    --table-text-color-1: #417d9e;
    --table-text-color-2: #ff0000;
    --table-text-color-3: #008000;
    --table-text-color-4: #b17b17;
    --table-text-color-5: rgb(87, 89, 146);
    --table-options-color: #22a7f0;
    --table-options-hover-color: #e6e6e6;
    --dropdown-line-hover: #ddd;
    --active-color: #87D37C;
    --passive-color: #E74C3C;
}
[data-theme="dark"] {
    --bg-color: #2f2f2f;
    --panel-bg: #1e262c;
    --panel-bg-hover: #2f3a42;
    --panel-border: #ffa500;
    --panel-title-color: #ffa500;
    --panel-title-hover: #ffffffc2;
    --panel-subtitle-color: #c3c6ce;
    --panel-text-color: #ffffff;
    --panel-button-bg: #dc4a4a;
    --panel-button-hover-bg: #d83535;
    --panel-button-text-color: #ffd7f8;
    --panel-button-text-hover-color: #ffd7f8;
    --input-bg: #1a2025;
    --input-border-color: #3694ff;
    --input-label-color: #cad1ff4d;
    --input-label-color-focus: #3694ff;
    --input-text-color: white;
    --search-input-bg: #1e262c;
    --table-shorting: #ffa500;
    --table-text-color-1: #417d9e;
    --table-text-color-2: #ff6262;
    --table-text-color-3: #358e65;
    --table-text-color-4: #3eafa4;
    --table-text-color-5: #40c57b;
    --table-options-color: #ffa500;
    --table-options-hover-color: #ffa50042;
    --dropdown-line-hover: #634747;
    --active-color: #0f980f;
    --passive-color: #bf1e0e;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
}
.squares { display: inline-block; margin-top: 30px;}
.square1 {display: inline-block; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: var(--table-text-color-1); margin-right: 20px;}
.square2 {display: inline-block;  width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: var(--table-text-color-2); margin-right: 20px;}
.square3 {display: inline-block;  width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: var(--table-text-color-3); margin-right: 20px;}
.square4 {display: inline-block;  width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: var(--table-text-color-4); margin-right: 20px;}

.theme-switch-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 10px;
}
.theme-switch {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 26px;
    position: relative;
    width: 52px;
}
.theme-switch input {
    display:none;
}
.slider {
    background-color: #ccc0;
    border: 3px solid #a5a4a4;
    bottom: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition: .4s;
}
.slider:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color: #a5a4a4;
    bottom: 1.8px;
    left: 3px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transition: .4s;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
#darklightswitch:checked + .slider {
    border: 3px solid #3694ff;
}
#darklightswitch:checked + .slider:before {
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 0 #3694ff;
    background: 0 0;
    left: 21.1px;
}
.slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="theme-switch-wrapper">
  <label class="theme-switch" for="darklightswitch">
   <input type="checkbox" id="darklightswitch" />
   <div class="slider round"></div>
  </label>
 </div>
  <div class="squares">
  <div class="square1"></div>
  <div class="square2"></div>
  <div class="square3"></div>
  <div class="square4"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

My source: https://dev.to/ananyaneogi/create-a-dark-light-mode-switch-with-css-variables-34l8

Pen: https://codepen.io/lastofdead/pen/dyPdPWY

**Edit:**

My real index page;

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="js/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.js?ver=1" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="css/darklight.css?ver=2.01" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/style.css?ver=2.02" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/print.css?ver=2.00" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="theme-switch-wrapper">
        <label class="theme-switch" for="darklightswitch">
            <input type="checkbox" id="darklightswitch" />
            <div class="slider round"></div>
        </label>
    </div>



    <!-- some divs -->



    <script src="js/darklightswitch.js?ver=2.04" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/dropdown-responsive.js?ver=2.00"></script>
    <script src='js/jquery.dataTables.min.js?ver=2.00' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/input.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/sweet-js.js?ver=2.00"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 2**

This is the last. I'm still having the same problem.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="js/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.js?ver=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');
        function switchTheme(e) {
            if (e.target.checked) {
                document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
                localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark'); //add this
            }
            else {
                document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
                localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light'); //add this
            }    
        }
        toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);
        /* çerezleme */
        const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme') ? localStorage.getItem('theme') : null;
        if (currentTheme) {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', currentTheme);
            if (currentTheme === 'dark') {
                toggleSwitch.checked = true;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <style>
        :root {
            --bg-color: #2f2f2f;
            --panel-bg: #fff;
            --panel-bg-hover: #dcd8d8;
            --panel-border: #22a7f0;
            --panel-title-color: #22a7f0;
            --panel-title-hover: #0072b1;
            --panel-subtitle-color: #ffa500;
            --panel-text-color: #000000;
            --panel-button-bg: #dc4a4a;
            --panel-button-hover-bg: #d83535;
            --panel-button-text-color: #ffd7f8;
            --panel-button-text-hover-color: #ffd7f8;
            --input-bg: #e6e6e6;
            --input-border-color: #ff0000;
            --input-label-color: #ff0000;
            --input-label-color-focus: #ff0000;
            --input-text-color: #000000;
            --search-input-bg: #fff;
            --table-shorting: #22a7f0;
            --table-text-color-1: #417d9e;
            --table-text-color-2: #ff0000;
            --table-text-color-3: #008000;
            --table-text-color-4: #b17b17;
            --table-text-color-5: rgb(87, 89, 146);
            --table-options-color: #22a7f0;
            --table-options-hover-color: #e6e6e6;
            --dropdown-line-hover: #ddd;
            --active-color: #87D37C;
            --passive-color: #E74C3C;
        }
        [data-theme="dark"] {
            --bg-color: #2f2f2f;
            --panel-bg: #1e262c;
            --panel-bg-hover: #2f3a42;
            --panel-border: #ffa500;
            --panel-title-color: #ffa500;
            --panel-title-hover: #ffffffc2;
            --panel-subtitle-color: #c3c6ce;
            --panel-text-color: #ffffff;
            --panel-button-bg: #dc4a4a;
            --panel-button-hover-bg: #d83535;
            --panel-button-text-color: #ffd7f8;
            --panel-button-text-hover-color: #ffd7f8;
            --input-bg: #1a2025;
            --input-border-color: #3694ff;
            --input-label-color: #cad1ff4d;
            --input-label-color-focus: #3694ff;
            --input-text-color: white;
            --search-input-bg: #1e262c;
            --table-shorting: #ffa500;
            --table-text-color-1: #417d9e;
            --table-text-color-2: #ff6262;
            --table-text-color-3: #358e65;
            --table-text-color-4: #3eafa4;
            --table-text-color-5: #40c57b;
            --table-options-color: #ffa500;
            --table-options-hover-color: #ffa50042;
            --dropdown-line-hover: #634747;
            --active-color: #0f980f;
            --passive-color: #bf1e0e;
        }
    </style>
    <link href="css/style.css?ver=2.02" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/print.css?ver=2.00" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="theme-switch-wrapper">
        <label class="theme-switch" for="darklightswitch">
            <input type="checkbox" id="darklightswitch" />
            <div class="slider round"></div>
        </label>
    </div>



    <!-- some divs -->



    <script src="js/dropdown-responsive.js?ver=2.00"></script>
    <script src='js/jquery.dataTables.min.js?ver=2.00' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/input.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/sweet-js.js?ver=2.00"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is because your `css` is applying first when page loads, but then your `javascript` loads and then it converts to dark theme.

Comment: So I just need to move css to js?

Comment: no no, you have to write `javascript` before `css`

Comment: I added my real HTML in post. Please can you check for me? Bcs I tried what you told me, but it didn't work.

Comment: It would better if you could do this from the server side

Comment: i do not understand

Comment: Server side; using php to generate the page on the server before sending it to the user. So it didn't work to move this part  `<script src="js/darklightswitch.js?ver=2.04" type="text/javascript"></script>` under the `<!-- JS -->` section in your `head` tag? Try adding the code inline instead, instead of linking to a document.

Comment: A clean solution would be with a loader. Show the loader until JS is loaded then show site.

Comment: @Wimanicesir I don't like loaders. They can create a lot of problems in the future. At least for me.

Comment: I assume that your code for adding a `data-theme` attribute were in your darklightswitch file, and I also assume that your CSS that you provided is in the same file.

Comment: @RickardElimää I tried. But doesn't work. http://prntscr.com/qke08s

Comment: @RickardElimää I added last version. Can you check for me?

Comment: It's working, but you're trying to find `toggleSwitch` before it's created in the DOM, hence your getting an error. The code starting from `const currentTheme` is the only thing you need to add before the inline CSS. You will still get an error, because you're referencing toggleSwitch in that code part too. @awran's answer is closest to what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the perfect solution for myself. @awran5 's  solution worked well. But it was like hell for slow internet and computers. Because the site was opening piece by piece. That didn't look very good either. I'm writing this for alternative seekers.

My solution is the database.

First of all, I get the person's theme selection from the database.

```
$getheme = mysql_query("SELECT theme FROM accounts WHERE id='$accountid'");
$pull = mysql_fetch_array($getheme);
$currentheme = $pull['theme'];
```

(I know, mysql_ very old. I'll replace it with mysqli_ as soon as possible. )

I add this to the body.

```
<body data-theme="<?php echo $currentheme ?>">
```

I gave input a name.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="darklightswitch"  name="darklightswitch" />
```

Switch needs to know which theme we're in.

```
const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('input[name="darklightswitch"]');
const currentTheme = "<?php echo $currentheme; ?>";
if (currentTheme === 'dark') {
    toggleSwitch.checked = true;
}
```

Finally, when we change Switch, the new theme value should go to the database.

```
$('input[name=darklightswitch]').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    if($("#darklightswitch").prop('checked') == true) {
        var theme = "dark";
    } else if ($("#darklightswitch").prop('checked') == false) {
        var theme = "light";
    }

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'themeswitch.php',
        data: {aid: <?php echo $accountid; ?>, theme: theme},
        success:function(result){
            location.reload();
        }
    });

});
```

themeswitch.php

```
$account_id = htmlspecialchars($_POST["aid"]);
$theme = htmlspecialchars($_POST["theme"]);

mysql_query("UPDATE accounts SET theme = '$theme' WHERE id='$account_id'");
```

Final content;

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <style type="text/css">
        [data-theme="light"] {
            --bg-color: #2f2f2f;
            --panel-bg: #fff;
            --panel-bg-hover: #dcd8d8;
            --panel-border: #22a7f0;
            --panel-title-color: #22a7f0;
            --panel-title-hover: #0072b1;
            --panel-subtitle-color: #ffa500;
            --panel-subtitle-color-hover: #22a7f0;
            --panel-text-color: #000000;
            --panel-button-bg: #dc4a4a;
            --panel-button-hover-bg: #d83535;
            --panel-button-text-color: #ffd7f8;
            --panel-button-text-hover-color: #ffd7f8;
            --input-bg: #e6e6e6;
            --input-border-color: #ff0000;
            --input-label-color: #ff0000;
            --input-label-color-focus: #ff0000;
            --input-text-color: #000000;
            --search-input-bg: #fff;
            --table-shorting: #22a7f0;
            --table-text-color-1: #417d9e;
            --table-text-color-2: #ff0000;
            --table-text-color-3: #008000;
            --table-text-color-4: #b17b17;
            --table-text-color-5: rgb(87, 89, 146);
            --table-options-color: #22a7f0;
            --table-options-hover-color: #e6e6e6;
            --dropdown-line-hover: #ddd;
            --active-color: #87D37C;
            --passive-color: #E74C3C;
        }
        [data-theme="dark"] {
            --bg-color: #2f2f2f;
            --panel-bg: #1e262c;
            --panel-bg-hover: #2f3a42;
            --panel-border: #ffa500;
            --panel-title-color: #ffa500;
            --panel-title-hover: #ffffffc2;
            --panel-subtitle-color: #c3c6ce;
            --panel-subtitle-color-hover: #ffa500;
            --panel-text-color: #ffffff;
            --panel-button-bg: #dc4a4a;
            --panel-button-hover-bg: #d83535;
            --panel-button-text-color: #ffd7f8;
            --panel-button-text-hover-color: #ffd7f8;
            --input-bg: #1a2025;
            --input-border-color: #3694ff;
            --input-label-color: #cad1ff4d;
            --input-label-color-focus: #3694ff;
            --input-text-color: white;
            --search-input-bg: #1e262c;
            --table-shorting: #ffa500;
            --table-text-color-1: #417d9e;
            --table-text-color-2: #ff6262;
            --table-text-color-3: #358e65;
            --table-text-color-4: #3eafa4;
            --table-text-color-5: #40c57b;
            --table-options-color: #ffa500;
            --table-options-hover-color: #ffa50042;
            --dropdown-line-hover: #634747;
            --active-color: #0f980f;
            --passive-color: #bf1e0e;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- FONT -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet prefetch">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css'>
    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- CSS -->    
    <link href="css/style.css?ver=22" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<?php
$getheme = mysql_query("SELECT theme FROM accounts WHERE id='$accountid'");
$pull = mysql_fetch_array($getheme);
$currentheme = $pull['theme'];
?>
<body data-theme="<?php echo $currentheme ?>">
    <div class="theme-switch-wrapper">
        <label class="theme-switch" for="darklightswitch">
            <input type="checkbox" id="darklightswitch" name="darklightswitch" />
            <div class="slider round"></div>
        </label>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('input[name=darklightswitch]').click(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');

            if($("#darklightswitch").prop('checked') == true) {
                var theme = "dark";
            } else if ($("#darklightswitch").prop('checked') == false) {
                var theme = "light";
            }

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'themeswitch.php',
                data: {aid: <?php echo $accountid; ?>, theme: theme},
                success:function(result){
                    location.reload();
                }
            });

        });
    </script>





    // some content





    <script type="text/javascript">
        const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('input[name="darklightswitch"]');
        const currentTheme = "<?php echo $currentheme; ?>";
        if (currentTheme === 'dark') {
            toggleSwitch.checked = true;
        }
    </script>
    <script src='js/jquery.dataTables.min.js?ver=2.00' type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you dont need js to update the switch. you can make it all server side

Answer (score 2):

This is not a typical solution but i guess it will do the trick and will reduce the load time as possible.

**Your structure should look like this:**

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- -->
<style>/* INLINE CSS */</style>
<!-- OTHER CSS STYLESHEETS -->
</head>
<body>

<!-- CONTENT -->

<!-- INLINE JS -->
<!-- OTHER DEFERRED JS SCRIPTS -->
</body>
</html>
```

---

**In your example :**

```html
<head>
<!-- meta -->
<style>
/* Inline critical CSS */
/* Define style directly, no need for root */
[data-theme="light"] {
  --bg-color: #fff;
  --panel-bg: #fff;
  --panel-bg-hover: #dcd8d8;
  --panel-border: #22a7f0;
  --panel-title-color: #22a7f0;
  --panel-title-hover: #0072b1;
  --panel-subtitle-color: #ffa500;
  --panel-text-color: #000000;
  --panel-button-bg: #dc4a4a;
  --panel-button-hover-bg: #d83535;
  --panel-button-text-color: #ffd7f8;
  --panel-button-text-hover-color: #ffd7f8;
  --input-bg: #e6e6e6;
  --input-border-color: #ff0000;
  --input-label-color: #ff0000;
  --input-label-color-focus: #ff0000;
  --input-text-color: #000000;
  --search-input-bg: #fff;
  --table-shorting: #22a7f0;
  --table-text-color-1: #417d9e;
  --table-text-color-2: #ff0000;
  --table-text-color-3: #008000;
  --table-text-color-4: #b17b17;
  --table-text-color-5: rgb(87, 89, 146);
  --table-options-color: #22a7f0;
  --table-options-hover-color: #e6e6e6;
  --dropdown-line-hover: #ddd;
  --active-color: #87D37C;
  --passive-color: #E74C3C;
}

[data-theme="dark"] {
  --bg-color: #2f2f2f;
  --panel-bg: #1e262c;
  --panel-bg-hover: #2f3a42;
  --panel-border: #ffa500;
  --panel-title-color: #ffa500;
  --panel-title-hover: #ffffffc2;
  --panel-subtitle-color: #c3c6ce;
  --panel-text-color: #ffffff;
  --panel-button-bg: #dc4a4a;
  --panel-button-hover-bg: #d83535;
  --panel-button-text-color: #ffd7f8;
  --panel-button-text-hover-color: #ffd7f8;
  --input-bg: #1a2025;
  --input-border-color: #3694ff;
  --input-label-color: #cad1ff4d;
  --input-label-color-focus: #3694ff;
  --input-text-color: white;
  --search-input-bg: #1e262c;
  --table-shorting: #ffa500;
  --table-text-color-1: #417d9e;
  --table-text-color-2: #ff6262;
  --table-text-color-3: #358e65;
  --table-text-color-4: #3eafa4;
  --table-text-color-5: #40c57b;
  --table-options-color: #ffa500;
  --table-options-hover-color: #ffa50042;
  --dropdown-line-hover: #634747;
  --active-color: #0f980f;
  --passive-color: #bf1e0e;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
}

.theme-switch-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
}

.theme-switch {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 26px;
  position: relative;
  width: 52px;
}

.theme-switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  background-color: #ccc0;
  border: 3px solid #a5a4a4;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: #a5a4a4;
  bottom: 1.8px;
  left: 3px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

#darklightswitch:checked+.slider {
  border: 3px solid #3694ff;
}

#darklightswitch:checked+.slider:before {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 0 #3694ff;
  background: 0 0;
  left: 21.1px;
}

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}
</style>

<!-- LINK OTHER CSS STYLESHEETS -->
</head>

<body>

<!-- CONTENT HERE -->

<script>
  // Pure JS not need for jQuery
  // getElementById will save you some Millisecond
  const toggleSwitch = document.getElementById('darklightswitch'); 
  // First thing first check for saved value
  const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme") || null;
  if (currentTheme) {
    document.body.setAttribute("data-theme", currentTheme);
    if (currentTheme === "dark") toggleSwitch.checked = true
  }
  // If not for some reasons set a fallback
  else {
    document.body.setAttribute("data-theme", "light");
  }

  toggleSwitch.addEventListener("change", e => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      document.body.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark");
      localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
    } else {
      document.body.setAttribute("data-theme", "light");
      localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
    }
  });
</script>
<!-- OTHER JS SCRIPTS Add defer tag to all -->
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
<script src="js/sweetalert2.all.js" defer></script>
<script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.js?ver=1" type="text/javascript" defer></script> 

</body>
```

---

**You can test live example** [Here](https://light-dark-theme.now.sh/)

Comment: Excellent. Everything works properly. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is call the javascript function right after opening of body tag. Then in the function get the theme type is it dark or light and add that class to body.

For this to work your css has to be structure like mine.

this way you dont need loadiang splash or backend to handle it

```css
div, p{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  color: red;
}
body.dark div, body.dark p{
  background: black;
}

body.light div, body.light p{
  background: grey;
}

body.dark .heading{
  font-size: 6em;
}

body.light .heading{
  font-size: 1.7em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function changeTheme(){
    var themeClassName = "dark"; // get it from cookie
    $("body").addClass(themeClassName);
  }
</script>

<body>
  <script>changeTheme()</script>
  
  <div>
    hello
  </div>
  <p class="heading">
    world
  </p>

</body>
```

Comment: This may be an alternative solution. But I've spent a lot of time on it.

Comment: if you have two separate css files for you themes it would not take a lot of time to restructure it. Otherwise, yes. You would need time to make two theme

Answer (score -1):

You can also add a Loading Splash that displays while your js loads.

Comment: well...Either someone can scroll down on the comments, or they can scroll down and easily find the solution of adding a splash.